# How to match one argument in a data that has multiple arguments with other data?

Tags: haskell

I have a created a data similarly like this

```
data Set = Set Integer [Char]

set1 :: [Set]
set1 = [ Set 1 ['a','f','k']
         ,Set 2 ['p','q','s']
       ]
```

If a given char is in the set1 function and it returns element in set1 or Nothing

```
checkChar :: Char -> [Set] -> Maybe Set
```

if i given **'p'** to checkChar function with **set1** as another parameter,then it should return **Set 2 ['p','q','s']**

what i tried

```
checkChar x [] =  Nothing
checkChar x (Set y [z] : Set ys [zs])   --Line 1
   | x `elem` [z] = Just $ Set y [z]
   | otherwise = checkChar x (Set ys [zs])  --Line 2
```

I got following errors for **Line 1 and 2**

```
Couldn't match expected type ‘[Set]’ with actual type ‘Set’
```

How to solve this?

How to match data that consists multiple arguments but want to check with one of the its argument with other data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not write `(… : Set ys zs)`. The `(:)` data constructor expects as second item a *list* of `Set`s not a `Set` object.

You can match this with:

```
checkChar :: Char -> [Set] -> Maybe Set
checkChar x [] = Nothing
checkChar x (Set y z : xs)
   | x `elem` z = Just (Set y z)
   | otherwise = checkChar x xs
```

Here we use `xs` as tail, which is a (possibly) empty list of `Set`s. Furthermore by using as pattern `Set y z`, this would only match lists with *exactly one* item. By using `z`, `z` will be assigned the entire list of items of the `Set` object.